# Rate of convergence in nonlinear system with unknown steady-state

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics

I ask for help in mathematicians, specialists in the theory of differential equations.

$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$

where $f(x)$ - unknown unimodal function.
For example: $f(x)=−(x−x_∗)^2$ or $f(x)=e^{(−(x−x_∗))^2}$

**About convergence:**

If we substitute such a function into the equation $\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$, then the solution will always converge from the initial point $x(0)$ to the one at which the extremum of the function is reached, i e. $x_∗$

**Assumptions:**

Suppose we know that $f(x)$ is unimodal, but we do not know the position of the maximum/minimum (we do not know $x_∗$).

It is assumed that the steady-state of the system exists, but it is not known in advance.

**Question:**
How to create exponential rate convergence in such a system?

I will illustrate the dynamics on the example of the function $f(x)=e^{(−(x−x_∗))^2}$ and what I need to get. There is my code in Mathematica:

```
Clear["Derivative"]

ClearAll["Global`*"]

pars = {xstart = -1, xend = 1}

f = Exp[-(x[t] - xend)^2]

sys = NDSolve[{ x'[t] == D[f, x[t]], x[0] == xstart}, {x}, {t, 0, 500}]

Plot[{Evaluate[x[t] /. sys], xend}, {t, 0, 300}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

What I have ($x_*=1, x(0)=-1$)
[image]

And what I want to get:
[image]

What I have ($x_*=-1, x(0)=1$)
[image]

And what I want to get:
[image]

*Let me remind you to assumption:* we do not know the position of the extremum and the structure of the function, but we know that it is unimodal (has a maximum or a minimum)

Comment: I am afraid there is no way to ensure exponential convergence rate. Plus I am not sure how you would tackle the problem, the "global" steady state, if it exists, is automatically given by the position of the maximum of $f$ (and not the minimum, this is not a steady state in this case).

Comment: Amazing! Solutions of this complex task does not exist.

Comment: @nicomezi

Please, see my new question:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4096460/problem-with-the-continuous-equivalent-of-newtons-method-optimization